# Fourier series formula with finite sums

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Let $f\in C(\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z})$, meaning that $f$ is continuous with period $2\pi$. Let $x_N(j)=2\pi j/N$. Define $$c_N(n)=\dfrac1N\sum_{j=1}^Nf(x_N(j))e^{-ix_N(j)n}.$$ Show that for any integer $M$, $$f(x_N(j))=\sum_{n=-M}^{N-M-1}c_N(n)e^{ix_N(j)n}.$$

This looks like the Fourier series formula, but the Fourier series comes with the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. Here there are only finite sums. How do we prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asked to prove the formula for the [Discrete Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). The continuous periodic function is largely irrelevant, since we only deal with its values on the uniform grid $x_j$. Presumably there is some way to get DFT from continuous Fourier transform, but I would not bother: the DFT is simpler, since we work in a finite dimensional space:  the space  of  $N$-periodic functions on the grid $\frac{2\pi}{N}\mathbb Z$. This space if $N$-dimensional, with natural inner product $\langle f,g\rangle =\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} f(j)\overline{g(j)}$. The vectors $f_k$, $k=0,\dots,N-1$, defined by $f_k(j) = \exp(ijk/N)$, are   orthogonal. Each has norm $\sqrt{N}$. Hence, every function $f$ is expanded as $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} c_k f_k$ where $c_k=\frac{1}{N}\langle f,f_k\rangle$. This was the formula to be proved. Lastly, the interval $j=0,\dots,N-1$ could be replaced by any interval of the same length, due to periodicity.

Comment: Thanks. How do you know that every function $f$ is expanded as $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}c_kf_k$? Sure, the $f_k$'s are orthogonal, but do we need to know that they're complete or something like that?

Comment: @MikaH. The space is $N$-dimensional. Any $N$ linearly independent vectors form its basis. This is what I meant when I remarked that having a finite dimensional space of functions makes the problem simpler.